# Mapping a OneToOne relationship within the same table with discriminator column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, one-to-one

I have a problem that resembles the following structure.

> Entity Car is an abstract entity that can be derived into CityCar, StationWagon, PickUp... - 
> Each Car has one Engine, which is an abstract entity for a FuelEngine, DieselEngine, HybridEngine, etc...

Since this is an indentifying `OneToOne` relationship, database design merged the two entities in the same table (I'm writing the following SQL by hand, I'm a bit rusty with SQL right now)

```
CREATE TABLE CAR (
    ID UNSIGNED INT PRIMARY KEY,
    TYPE_OF_CAR CHAR,
    LICENSE_PLATE VARCHAR(...),
    ....
    ENGINE_TYPE CHAR,
    ENGINE_CYLINDRATE DECIMAL, //let's say doesn't apply to ENGINE_TYPE='ELECTRIC'
    ENGINE_KW_POWER DECIMAL(...) NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

Now I want to map it in Hibernate. I am confident with syntax for `Car` class and subclasses. Currently, my POJO looks as following:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(SINGLE.TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(TYPE_OF_CAR)
public class Car{

    private int id;

    ....

    private char engineType;
    private float engineCylindrate;

    ....

}
```

The question is: is it possible to have the POJO show the property `private Engine engine;` instead of having all Engine attributes **without having a separate table for Engines**? How should the Engine class look like to not have its own table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note, such a database design will of course lead to plenty of columns which will have most of the time null values: size of cargo area for of pickups for all other cars as well, electric motor specific attributes for all rows, etc.

Same row in database cannot match to two different JPA entities. Consequently separate table for Car and Engine is required if also Engine should be entity. That would also lead to nicer model.

If that is not feasible, there is still other approach.  JPA way to group properties to separate class is using [@Embeddable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html). Because JPA does not support inheritance of embeddables (at least not mentioned in specification, Hibernate not supporting: [HHH-1910](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1910)), there cannot be subtypes of engine then. As said before, better solution is to go with two (at least) tables.

Comment: The answer is satisfying. While your answer is a valid general principle, in my case I don't think I'll be allowed to insert an extra entity just because of a few columns (because the equivalent of Engine entity has < 15 columns)